# Saving CSV in place loses delimiter

Tags: excel, vba, csv, ms-access

From Access I open a CSV file with an instance of Excel, do some processing and then save the file.

```
Sub ImportFile(fp As String)

Dim xlApp as Excel.Application
Dim wb as Excel.Workbook

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fp)

' processing code...

wb.Save

End Sub
```

Later in the code the file is closed and I use the TransferText method to import the file to a table.

```
DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImportDelim, tableName:=uploadTable, _
    fileName:=fp, hasfieldnames:=True
```

The problem is that after the save all columns have been concatenated into column A, i.e. the delimiter has been lost.

I've saved in place `wb.Save` and I've saved over itself `wb.SaveAs wb.Path & "\" & wb.Name` with no difference.

I know I could do a SaveAs in a different format but these are very large files and having multiple copies of them would be inefficient. I could use the FSO to delete the original but I'd prefer a neater solution.

Can anyone shed any light on what the issue is here?

Comment: Sounds like you're not calling `DoCmd.TransferText` with the proper parameters. But as long as you're not providing a sample part of the file and the exact syntax you use to import it, we can't be sure.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - I've updated my post with the import code, it works fine with files that don't have the issue I described.

Comment: Where is the sample part of the file I asked for? (just copy-paste (parts of) 2 lines of the file you're importing)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I can't do that, it's sensitive medical data. What is it you wanted to look for in the sample data?

Comment: I want to check if it's valid .csv data (doesn't contain non-ASCII characters, contains proper separators, etc.). You can censor it, as long as you make sure the import returns the same concatenated result.

Comment: Spare yourself the grief and save as xls/xlsx. In addition, this will actually be more efficient if you are working with large files. `Kill fp` is all you need to delete the csv afterwards.

Comment: It's only sensitive if it's attached to personally identifying information. Sanitize the data, use dummy info but realistic in structure.